# Using multiple address locators in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, geocoding, arccatalog, address

I am geocoding millions of addresses for my research (every registered voter in six states).

I am using two geocoders: one that is really fast and one that has fewer unmatched addresses when I geocode.

Is there a way to use **ArcMap** or **ArcCatalog** to use the second address locator on only the unmatched addresses from the first?

Right now I am importing the attribute table using the R programming language, exporting only the unmatched addresses as a CSV, re-importing them to ArcGIS, and geocoding, but I figure there has to be a faster way.

Comment: Are you using geocoding services that are published by someone else, or are they in your control?

Comment: It could be either.  I've found the most accurate is ESRI's US Streets Geocode Service that's built into ArcGIS, but since I'm working with 6 different states, I have several local and national level address locators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a Composite Address Locator using ArcCatalog that has this functionality.  You first create your individual locators, then add them to the Composite locator.  You set the order of the individual locators in the composite locator setup.  If the address does not find a match in the first locator in the list, it is passed to the next locator in the list.

[ESRI Help Instructions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00250000003r000000)